# how to create a theme on shopify using PHP API

Tags: laravel, shopify

I am using PHP Shopify API to create the theme on my store. I am using the following code..

```
$sh= App::make('ShopifyAPI');
    $appSecret=env('SHOPIFY_PRIVATE_APP_SECRET');
    $appPassword=env('SHOPIFY_PRIVATE_APP_PASSWORD');
    $apiKey=env('SHOPIFY_PRIVATE_APP_API_KEY');
    $sh->setup(['API_KEY' => $apiKey, 'API_SECRET' => $appSecret, 'SHOP_DOMAIN' => 'myfirstappstore.myshopify.com/', 'ACCESS_TOKEN' => $appPassword]);
    $args=array(
        'METHOD'=>'POST',
        'URL'=>'themes.json',
        'HEADERS'=>array(),
        'CHARSET'=>'UTF-8',
        'DATA'=>array(
            "theme"=> array(
                "name"=> "foobar",
                "src"=> "http://myfirstappstore.myshopify.com/theme.zip",
                "role"=> "main"
            )
        ),
        'RETURNARRAY'=>TRUE,
        'ALLDATA'=>TRUE,
        'FAILONERROR'=>TRUE
    );

    try {
        $resultData = $sh->call($args);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $resultData = $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo"<pre>";print_r($resultData);die;
```

I am getting the error as

> ERROR #22: The requested URL returned error: 422 Unprocessable Entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `src` property would need to be set to a real URL, leading to a zip file that contains the theme. 
For example, `https://codeload.github.com/Shopify/skeleton-theme/zip/master` would be a valid src.